# How to retain client IP address after WCF routing?

Tags: wcf, routes, ip-address

I currently have a WCF service that is able to obtain the client IP address using the following code;

```
    private static string GetClientIPAddress()
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty clientEndpoint =
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[
            RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

        return clientEndpoint.Address;
    }
```

However, when we put a WCF routing service in front of the existing service, we now find that that the reported IP address is that of the server hosting the routing service.

Is it possible for the client IP address to be retained all the way though?